# If a system lies in a non-equilibrium state initially, and there are two possible equilibrium final states. How does the system evolve?

Tags: thermodynamics, non-equilibrium

This should be the area of non-equilibrium thermodynamics. The system is in a non-equilibrium state and after a long time it will evolve into an equilibrium state. But now we have two possible final equilibrium states with different temperatures. I guess the system will evolve into one final state under some conditions and into another final state under other situations. I want to know whether we have some methods to judge the final state.

As an example, we assume the system is composed of two parts. Initially, the two parts have different temperatures, T1 and T2. Thus the initial state is non-equilibrium. We know that the system must evolve into an equilibrium state with a constant temperature. But if the system can have two possible final states with different temperatures, can we judge which final state the system will be in?

Comment: Yes the system will evolve to an equilibrium state, but there are many possible final equilibrium states, not just two.  You need more info on the initial  non-equilibrium states

Comment: You need to provide more details on the system you are considering.

Comment: @Mark_Phys If final states are equivalent, then I see no reason why specific state would be preferred over the others. This hints that final state chosen would be pretty much in non-deterministic way, i.e. chaotic evolution. But your condition ("different temperatures") is like hint that these final states are not so equivalent. Then, it depends the process involved and many other conditions. For example, in adiabatic cooling system may go into a state with lower temperature.